# functions within functions in JS?

Tags: javascript

The problem I'm having with this code now seems to be with the function call within each function. The way it's roughly supposed to work is to check if the guessed letter is in the word array. I'll have to add more to it later to prevent looping once all letters in the word array have been guessed. For now though, I haven't been able to make the guessLetter function run a second time.

```js
var word = ['p', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'e'];
var guess = [];
var nextGuess;

function guessLetter() {
  nextGuess = window.prompt("Make a guess:", "");

  if (nextGuess !== "") {
    guess.push(nextGuess);
    checkLetter(guess);
  } else
    console.log("No guess made.");
}

function checkLetter(guess) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < word.length) {
    console.log('In checkLetter. guess index=' + guess[guess.length - 1] + ' guess=' + guess);
    if (word[i] == guess[guess.length - 1]) {
      console.log('In if of checkLetter');
      console.log('Current guessed letters: ' + guess + '. Found letter: ' + guess[guess.length - 1]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  guessLetter();
}

guessLetter();
```

Comment: When I try it it keeps asking for a letter.

Comment: well, as you can see...when this js gets put into a jsfiddle there seems to be no problem with it looping...as a matter of fact, the looping IS the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/5urg9op0/

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're having `guessLetter` call `checkLetter` call `guessLetter` ad infinitum instead of just using a loop (i.e. `while (nextGuess !== "")` in place of the `if` and dropping the `else` to after the loop) in `guessLetter`?

Comment: Also, FYI `guess[guess.length - 1]` will always give you the last letter for `index`.

Comment: @arcyqwerty That seems intentional. Since `guessLetter` pushed the last letter onto `guess`, `guess[guess.length-1]` is the last guess. It would be more obvious if he simply passed `nextGuess` as an argument to `checkLetter`.

Comment: Some tips: word.indexOf('o') returns 2, word.indexOf('z') returns -1. Additionally, strings can be treated like arrays in JS. So for var word = 'phone', word[2] will give you 'o'. Might help you slim some things down.

Comment: @Barmar and beauXjames Yea, it doesn't continuously loop for all single letter inputs though. All the different combinations I've tried are running together, but hopefully it'll come to me soon. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything that will stop the loop, unless it gets an error. Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: @arcyqwerty Maybe I should be using while (nextGuess !== ""). My reason for the if is cause my intent now is for the user to enter only one letter at a time, and so no need to loop over that.

Comment: One letter at a time, but you're entering letter after letter after letter right?The way you have it now, `checkLetter` always goes back to `guessLetter` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you, I use an object for this issue:https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/r33up7p7/

```
var getletters = {
    word : ['p', 'h','o','n','e'],
    guess : [],
    nextGuess : "",//letter
    count:0,
    guessLetter: function() {
        this.nextGuess = window.prompt("Make a guess:","");
        if (this.nextGuess !== "" && this.nextGuess !== false && this.nextGuess !== null) {
            this.guess.push(this.nextGuess);
            this.checkLetter();
        }else{
            console.log("No guess made.");
        } 
    },
    checkLetter() {
        for (i in this.word) {
            console.log('In checkLetter. guess index=' + this.guess[this.guess.length-1] + ' guess=' + this.guess);
            if (this.word[i] == this.guess[this.guess.length-1]) {
                console.log('In if of checkLetter');
                console.log('Current guessed letters: ' + this.guess + '. Found letter: ' + this.guess[this.guess.length-1]);
                this.count += 1;
            }
        }
        console.log('count hits:'+this.count);
        if(this.count == this.word.length){
            alert('you guess the letters: '+this.word);
        }else{
            this.guessLetter();
        }
    }
};
getletters.guessLetter();
```